# Get clicked element in an event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input element. And when focus out a div is closed, and as well I have a handler that when you click on an item in the div when input is onfocus, it changes a select inputs value. The problem is they dont work together. 
This, just overrides the whole thing:

```
    $('.$name input').on( 'blur', function(){
        $(this).siblings('div').eq(0).hide();
   });
```

and second handler:

```
    $('span.$name div ul').on('click', 'li', function(){
        var value = $(this).attr('value');
        $('span.$name select').val( value );
    });
```

How do I fix my issue? 
I tried to use event.target, in first handler, but it returns input box.

Here is Html code, if that helps:

```
<span class="test_name"><select id="peteris" class="mana-klase" style="width:200px;background-color:red; display:none;" inroto="test_name" name="test_name">
<option value="1">viens</option>
<option value="2" selected="selected">divi</option>
<option value="3">tris</option>
</select><input id="peteris" class="mana-klase" style="width:200px;background-color:red;" inroto="test_name" type="text" value="divi" name=""><div style="position: relative; top: -20px; left: 1px; width: 200px; display: none; background-color: blue;" inroto="test_name"><ul><li value="1">viens</li><li value="2">divi</li><li value="3">tris</li></ul></div>
        <script>
            var input = 'input[inroto="input-test_name"]';
            var div = 'div[inroto="div-test_name"]';
            var select = 'div[inroto="select-test_name"]';
            var span = 'div[inroto="span-test_name"]';

            if ( $(div).css('width') == '0px' )
            {
                var inputWidth = $( input ).css('width');
                $( div ).css('width', inputWidth );
            }




            $('.test_name input').on( 'blur', function(){
              $('span.test_name div ul').on('click', 'li', function(){
                var value = $(this).attr('value');
                $('span.test_name select').val( value );
            });
                $(this).siblings('div').eq(0).hide();
           });

            $('.test_name input').on( 'focusin', function(){
                $(this).siblings('div').eq(0).show();
            });


            $('.test_name input').on('keyup', function(){
                var that = this;
                var list = $(this).siblings('div').eq(0).children();
                $( list ).empty();

                var selected = $(this).siblings('select').eq(0).children();
                $(selected).each( function() {
                if ( $(this).html().indexOf( $( that ).val() ) != -1 )
                    $( list ).append('<li value="' + $(this).val() + '">' + $(this).html() + '</li>' );
                });
            });





        </script></span>
```

Whole handler for now:

```
   $('.$name input').on( 'blur', function(e){
        $('span.$name div ul').on('click', 'li', function(ev){
            var value = $(this).attr('value');
            var html = $(this).html();
            console.log(value);
            $('span.$name select').val( value );
            $('span.$name input').val( html );

            $('span.$name div').hide(); 
        });
    });
```

and If I want that div closes always when focus out:

```
 $('.$name input').on( 'blur', function(e){
        $('span.$name div ul').on('click', 'li', function(ev){
            var value = $(this).attr('value');
            var html = $(this).html();
            console.log(value);
            $('span.$name select').val( value );
            $('span.$name input').val( html );

        });

            $('span.$name div').hide(); 
    });
```

Last example doesnt work.

Comment: Well for one you should probably fix your HTML. You should probably be using div instead of span and also put your js script not within the span.

Comment: Yes, I know, I will do it when it all will work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('.$name input').on( 'blur', function(e){
            $(e.currentTarget).siblings('div').eq(0).hide();
       });

        $('span.$name div ul').on('click', 'li', function(e){
            var value = $(e.currentTarget).attr('value');
            $('span.$name select').val( value );
        });
```

EDITED**

Try adding

```
   $('.test_name input').on( 'focusin', function(){
                $(this).siblings('div').eq(0).show();
                $(this).trigger( 'keyup' );
            });
```

which will trigger your func on when it focuses so it runs the selection stuff

Comment: Nop, it doesnt. Tried, event that.

Comment: What are you trying to do? I dont understand. Are you trying to make the list element that is clicked show in the input box?

Comment: See edit with trigger to run the selection process when you focus so it narrows the list and fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/s47r3e66/

Comment: Thanks, but it doesnt resolve my initial problem. When you click on list element it doesnt change hidden select fields value, but if I disable  $(this).siblings('div').eq(0).hide(); it works fine.

Comment: I think you need to do a lot of work on trying to explain your issues. I'm still not understanding what you want. Maybe someone else will be able to help you out. Sorry.

Comment: This part of script doesnt work:

        $('span.$name div ul').on('click', 'li', function(e){
            var value = $(e.currentTarget).attr('value');
            $('span.$name select').val( value );
        });
I dont know why, Imo its because its in another event handler.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if i did really understand your question, but you might check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wvgpp1z4/) for a working example. Just have changed a par of things: added this two lines of code:

```
$('.test_name input').val($(this).text());
$('span.test_name div').hide();
```

and removed:

```
$(this).siblings('div').eq(0).hide();
```

Hope it useful!

Comment: Thanks you all. It still doesnt work as I want. When you choose one list element it hides div with hold all list elements and if you click anywhere else it hides div. but it doesnt seem to work. I will post script on question( on top ).